# Efficiency - setInterval vs Object.watch

Tags: javascript, performance, algorithm

I have a question regarding efficiency in JavaScript.  I want to create a 'watcher' that watches a particular member and, upon change, executes a function.  I have seen two methods:

1) A set interval that continuously compares the old value against the current value and fires the callback when there is a change

2) Object.watch

I have read that Object.watch creates some overhead, but I was curious as to which method above is the most efficient?  If there are other methods, feel free to let me know!

Comment: All code you write and execute "creates some overhead". Do you have an actual performance problem? If not, pick whichever leads to correct code easier. Saying "X is more efficient than Y" when they're both completely different mechanisms, with different performance characteristics, that happen to accomplish the same thing is pretty much nonsensical.

Comment: Heh, actually no it's not "nonsensical".  Algorithms are important when it comes to boilerplate code.  Otherwise, you end up with O(n^x) complexity as you build on top of it.

Comment: You're not writing an algorithm, and this isn't on a critical code path, and namedropping exponential complexity is overly melodramatic when the difference is probably different values of `n` in `O(n)`, and the only information you have is "I read about some overhead", and the whole thing is likely negligible compared to the rest of your code. The mechanism that fires the change notification will likely be much smaller than anything you do based on that notification.

Comment: How exactly does your writing a framework place the overhead caused by either of these functions on the critical code path? The overhead they incur won't be located when you call those functions themselves, but when either a) the `setInterval()` handler fires (and figures out what changed etc.); or b) the observed properties change (and all the change notification handlers fire). It's literally impossible to tell whether a) or b) will occur more frequently without knowing how they're used in your framework and in whatever is based on that framework, much less which will be ultimately "faster".

Comment: Also, the way to find out the truth is profiling with a realistic load. Or at least benchmarking: http://jsperf.com/observe-vs-setter. Which tells us that `Object.observe()` is, in fact, ridiculously slow and worth avoiding if it won't affect your design too much. `defineProperty` on the other hand seems be on par with a wrapper function. Both are much slower than not bothering with either, so a timed poll *might* be faster, if it can determine what changed quickly enough. This is more likely the fewer objects it needs to keep track of. This also makes it impossible to add it to the benchmark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also wrap the member in an update function which fires an event after setting a new value, and listen for the event elsewhere in your code. That would be pretty efficient.

Comment: This is a better approach.

Comment: This works.  I'll simply design this portion of the framework to use a key-value pair interface to set members.

Answer (score 0):

(Side note: You should use `Object.observe()` as `Object.watch()` is FF specific.)

If this is about particular property then it is better in many senses to use virtual property mechanism and provide your own setter. Check [Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

Comment: This is more of a boiler plate function, very generic.